# what if i change visibility for different layouts in one activity instead of starting new activities?

Tags: android

i'm trying to change **visibility** to **gone** for current layout and set new layout visible instead of using **activities**.
does it have effect on performance?

```
<include layout="@layout/page1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

and in Mainctivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        page1button.setOnClickListener{
            page1.visibility = View.GONE
            page2.visibility = View.VISIBLE  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are talking about fragments without knowing that the concept is called fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies) :

> When your app processes an object for layout, the app performs the
>   same process on all children of the layout as well.

So the bigger the layouts are and the more complicated they are, the bigger the use of memory by the system. The logic and maintenance of it could become difficult too in long term.

So as [Tejas Trivedi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911539/4499937) said, use fragments.

Answer (score 2):

instead of change visibility of your layouts you can do it with [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) it is easy way to do it.